# How do I allow other applications to open a file I need to hold open?

Tags: c++, windows, file-permissions, file-access

I have a C++ windows application which opens a file (and keeps it open) as follows:

```
FILE* fp = NULL;
errno_t result = _wfopen_s(&fp, L"MyRawData.dat", L"wb");
```

This works fine but when I try and serve that file up via filezilla it denies access to the file when I try and download it (despite ticking the 'Allow downloading of files which are open for writing by another process' option).

Is this something I've done wrong in my software or a limitation of Filezilla / general windows issue?

Comment: That's likely off topic, but what does the `L` mean in front of the string literals?

Comment: The L prefix makes the string a wchar_t string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of said function:

> Files opened by `fopen_s` and `_wfopen_s` are not sharable. If you require that a file be sharable, use `_fsopen`, `_wfsopen` with the appropriate sharing mode constant (for example, `_SH_DENYNO` for read/write sharing).

Comment: yes, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db(v=vs.110).aspx) for all options